# Extracting data from a struct using a loop with specific field names

Tags: matlab

I'm importing data from an HDF5 file using h5read, which outputs a struct with named fields. Currently, I'm attempting to get the size of each of these fields.

```
for n = 1:namesSizeH5
    currentName = strcat('h5(1).',namesH5((0+n):n));
    currentSize = size(currentName);
    disp('currentName is');
    disp(currentName);
    disp('currentSize is');
    disp(currentSize);
end
```

When this runs, it correctly grabs the current field name for each iteration, as well as constructing the correct struct call to get to each field in order. However, currentSize will always return only the size of the struct.
I have tested this by hardcoding in the correct call, which works, but breaks when in the loop.

Comment: `strcat` returns a string, so `size` will return the size of the string. I suggest trying the [correct syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following code explains how to get the size of each field in a struct. Just adapt the code to your situation.

```
% Create struct
sampleStruct.field1 = 'This is field 1';
sampleStruct.field2 = true(5);
sampleStruct.field3 = randn(1,5);

% Get fieldnames
fnames = fieldnames(sampleStruct);

% Display fields size
for i=1:length(fnames)
    disp(['Field name is: ' fnames{i}]);
    fieldValue = sampleStruct.(fnames{i});
    fieldSize = size(fieldValue);
    disp(['Field size is: ' mat2str(fieldSize)]);
end
```

The output is:

```
Field name is: field1
Field size is: [1 15]
Field name is: field2
Field size is: [5 5]
Field name is: field3
Field size is: [1 5]
```

Useful function: `fieldnames`. Just type `doc fieldnames` in the Command Windows to view the help documentation.

Recommended reading: 
http://imageprocessinglog.com/tutorials/matlab-structures-datatype/